# Exports have random double quotes

Tags: sql-server, export, ssms, quotes

Why does the same field in different records have double quotes?  Whenever the first field begins with double quote it is also padded with spaces to the right.  Also, notice that some last fields end with double quote and others do not. Another weird thing is when exporting to Flat File, Code Page 65001(UTF-8) is auto selected and would not export. Perhaps it is sensing this in the data?  1252 ANSI Latin 1 works for the example below. There is no difference if I used “ for text exported CSV or not.  Output is the same. The table data does not have quotes. [Tbl Def 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/eccxO.jpg)
[Tbl Def2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EP6hi.jpg)

Comment: Export from/using what?

Comment: Can you also show us the table definition.

Comment: Used SSMS to Export, added pics of table definition to original question.

Comment: Is it the double quote character causing the spaces, or the spaces causing the double quotes? I expect if you `select datalength(F01) from dbo.Lbldesc where F01 = N'00000000000010'` you'll get `40` as the result instead of `28` because that particular value includes 6 trailing spaces.